# Recover NTFS file system from RAW partition w/o recovering individual files

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs

There is an NTFS partition with data that was converted into RAW partition by a piece of software. Now it's not readable. File recovery utils easily find all the files (including deleted ones) and it's no problem to recover data file by file.

But is there a way to recover the file system as a whole (including metadata, like creation time)?

Essentially I am looking for a way of undoing the covertation of the NTFS partition into RAW.

Comment: "Converted into RAW partition" is a euphemism. "Broken" is the truth. RAW is not something you convert to. RAW is what Windows tells you when it finds no filesystem it recognizes. Even garbage is RAW in this context.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's the case.

Comment: @DenisKulagin [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). What you're looking to do is recover the partition table